# Ubuntu Server 20.04LTS with GUI - constantly freezing

Tags: server, gui, lts

I have fresh installed Ubuntu Server LTS. I have installed xorg and ubuntu-desktop (second time). After install gui system is constantly freezing for 10-20 seconds in regular periods of time. There is no hardware issues with my computer (ubuntu desktop, W7, Gentoo and Manjaro was running fine on it). Without GUI everything works fine, but i'm too lazy, and have too little time to learn how to configure and use it from shell... Can anybody help me? (sorry - my english isn't very good :-( )

1. I'm using screen to view GUI :D
2. My PC:
   Asrock Q1900B-ITX + 12GB DDR3 RAM, integrated graphics, 250GB HDD SATA, WN722N WiFi and thats it...
3. It doesnt matter if i use Wifi or Ethernet...
4. At startup it wait for about 1-2minutes for Network config... ? Why?
   During the installation i was connected to the internet using ethernet (directly to router without any authorization or config needed), after instaling GUI and Network Manager i switched to WiFi -> and i dont see ethernet under NetworkManager... Why?
5. There is enough free space for swapping, nothing in /var/crash and at htop at the moment of freeze the currently used process is using 100% of 1-2 cores... and after that everything is normal again..

Comment: What are you using to view the GUI (VNCViewer, etc)?

Comment: If you want GUI then install Ubuntu desktop, it's that simple. And for any chance of getting a meaningful answer please edit the question with hardware specifications.

Comment: Unfortunately, you have not provided any useful diagnostic information yet. When I add `ubuntu-desktop` to an Ubuntu Server, it works properly. Check your logs. check `top` for resource hogs. Check `free` for swapping. Look for crash reports in /var/crash. A freeze could have a dozen possible causes. Help us to help you.